# Taking only values which form continous range

Tags: perl

I have a file with 3 columns ->

```
A1  0   9
A1  4   14
A1  16  24
A1  25  54
A1  64  84
A1  74  84
A2  15  20
A2  19  50
```

I want to check if each line (value in col2 and 3) is present already or is in between the range of previous line, if col1 value is equal.
The desired output is ->

```
A1  0   14
A1  16  54
A1  64  84
A2  15  50
```

I have tried ->

```
@ARGV or die "No input file specified";
open $first, '<',$ARGV[0] or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
#open $second,'<', $ARGV[1] or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
$k=0;
while (<$first>) 
{
if($k==0)
{
@cols = split /\s+/;
$p0=$cols[0];
$p1=$cols[1];
$p2=$cols[2];
$p3=$cols[2]+1;
}

else{
@new = split /\s+/;
if ($new[0] eq $p0){
    if ($new[1]>$p3)
        {
    print join("\t", @new),"\n";
    $p0=$new[0];
    $p1=$new[1];
    $p2=$new[2];
    $p3=$new[2]+1;


        }
    elsif ($new[2]>=$p2) 
    {
    print $p0,"\t",$p1,"\t",$new[2],"\n";
    $p2=$new[2];
    $p3=$new[2]+1;
    }

    else 
        {
    $p5=1;

        }   
}

      else 
      {
    print join("\t", @new),"\n";
        $p0=$new[0];
    $p1=$new[1];
    $p2=$new[2];
    $p3=$new[2]+1;

      }}
      $k=1;

}
```

and output I am getting is ->

```
A1    0       14
A1    16      24
A1    16      54
A1    64      84
A1    64      84
A2    15      20
A2    22      50
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting this wrong output. Also if there is any way that I can erase(or overwrite) the last printed line, then it will be very easy.

Comment: Use one of the various span/range/interval modules: http://p3rl.org/News::Newsrc http://p3rl.org/Number::Interval http://p3rl.org/Parse::Range http://p3rl.org/Set::IntSpan [::Fast](http://p3rl.org/Set::IntSpan::Fast) [::XS](http://p3rl.org/Set::IntSpan::Fast::XS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it would be much more simple to help you if you

- used `strict` and `warnings`, and declared all your variabled close to first use with `my`
- indented your code properly to show the structure

The reason your code fails is that you are printing data under too many conditions. For example you output `A1  16  24` when you find it cannot be joined with the previous range `A1  4  14` without waiting for it to be extended by the subsequent `A1  25  54` (when you correctly extend the range and print it again). `A1 64  84` is output twice for the same reason: first because it cannot be merged with `A1  25  54`, and again because it has been "extended" with `A1  74  84`. Finally `A2  15  20` is output straight away because it has a new first column, even though it is merged with the next line and output again.

You need to output a range only when you have found that it cannot be extended again. That happens when

- a new record is found that doesn't overlap the existing data
- the end of the file is reached

This code prints output only in those cases an appears to do what you need.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data;

while (<DATA>) {

  if (not @data) {
    @data = split;
    next;
  }

  my @new = split;

  if ($new[0] eq $data[0] and $new[1] <= $data[2] + 1) {
    $data[2] = $new[2];
  }
  else {
    print join("\t", @data), "\n";
    @data = @new;
  }

  print join("\t", @data), "\n" if eof DATA;

}

__DATA__
A1  0   9
A1  4   14
A1  16  24
A1  25  54
A1  52  57
A1  59  62
A1  64  84
A1  74  84
A2  15  20
A2  19  50
```

**OUTPUT**

```
A1  0 14
A1  16  57
A1  59  62
A1  64  84
A2  15  50
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Next time, I will definitely post my code with good structure. Sorry, just a newbee and trying to learn. Also, I think, someone has edited your answer because now the conditions of if and else has been swapped, which is not working.

Comment: I reversed the `if`statement as well as the sense of the test because I prefer it that way. It still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some variables describing currently-accumulated contiguous region.  For each line of input, flush the previously-accumulated region if the new input is a new column1 label, or is same label but non-contiguous, or is end-of-file.  If it's same label and contiguous yo update the min and max values.

This assumes that columns 1 and 2 are sorted.

The rest is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my code, I am printing straight way if column 1 value is new. I am using these variables ($p0,p1,p2,p3) to store last values, so that I can compare them with the new ones, but result is not coming as I am expecting and I am not able to find a mistake here. Can you please give suggestion, that what mistake I have done in my code?